# Is the frame material of Specialized AWOL Comp and Elite the same?

Tags: steel, touring-bikes

I'm looking at these to bikes:

- [AWOL Elite](http://www.specialized.com/gb/gb/bikes/road/awol/awol-elite)
- [AWOL Comp](http://www.specialized.com/gb/gb/bikes/road/awol/awol-comp)

From the specs I can't decifer though if the frame material and/or alloy is the same on the two bikes?

I know the frames differ in other ways, but I won't need other drive trains, so I just want to know I can just as well buy the cheaper Elite.

Comment: what did Specialized say when you asked them?

Comment: There's definitely two different frame materials that you can get the AWOL in but I don't know if these two bikes cover the two.

Comment: From the webby, the two frames are different (at least they have more details on the Awol Comp (Reynolds 725/520 premium Cr-Mo)

Comment: Just shoot an email to Specialized? Or stop by your local specialized dealer (since you're going to have to buy it from them anyway).

Comment: @PeteH I asked the dealer, he could not tell me. I've sent the question to Specialized now.

Comment: @Batman same as the above :)

Comment: @Max It was exactly this difference in detail that left me confused.

Comment: Fingers crossed. I've had some success speaking to Giant (via Facebook of all things) so you do sometimes get meaningful responses from these big companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to bike rumors, these two bikes have different Cr-Mo tubing, with one being a higher end material. You can find more information [here](http://www.bikerumor.com/2013/07/17/2014-specialized-goes-awol-for-adventure-disc-for-cx/)

Comment: It is also normal that throughout the same bike range a brand uses different materials, such as different grades of carbon. An example is the Specialized Tarmac bikes, which despise different component packages vary from Fact 9 to Fact 10 carbons, being the later better but more expensive.

Comment: That site is called "bike rumors" for a reason. It's not authoritative.

Comment: Only in the the same way "bike radar" is not from the military. Bike rumors is just a name, the information there is as valid as any other bikes website.

Answer (score 1):

Same frame material. Not sure why it's not more detailed on the Elite specs, but there are several shops marketing it that reference the same frame materials as the Comp, like [this one](https://m.facebook.com/rocktownbicycles/posts/748908081834590).

Makes sense when you think about it. The Comp and Elite ultimately refer to different component packages (just like those annoying and less meaningful letters that come after car models), though I'm not sure why they don't just call the frame an AWOL!

Comment: The Comp (and AWOL frame set - US only) have a special rear rocker drop out that can be setup for derailleur gears, hub gears and as a single speed, while the Elite and low end "AWOL" model have a standard vertical drop out meant only for derailleur gears.

Comment: @Rider_X You should post it as an answer.

Comment: This answer is probably true though Spesh has never said so explicitly. Looking at the bicycle frames closely in person, there appears to be no difference in the tubing, nor is there an appreciable difference in the weight of the respective bare frames. Also: The AWOL Poler and the Comp have similar components. Poler is $50 more. Differences: Poler has the standard AWOL frame without the split stays, and a rack. It would be a surprise to see an inferior frame at the "high end" of the line. If the Poler had an inferior (significantly cheaper) frame, it could be priced $100 *less* than the Comp.